# PYODBC: I cannot run "GRANT SELECT ON AAA TO BBB", What I am doing wrong?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, sql-grant

I am using pyodbc.

```
query = "GRANT SELECT ON ABC.PROJE TO [MYDOMAIN\USER_1];"
connection.autocommit = True
cursor = connection.cursor()
result = cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

All I get is an exception:

> No Results. Previous SQL was not a query.

Is this method wrong, or are there any other ways to do this operation?

Thanks,

Comment: Why `result = cursor.execute(query)` when the query returns no rows? The error *is* telling you the problem. Also, why use `autocommit`, if you're then going to explicitly commit it?

Comment: Is "the query returns no rows" mean I couldn't give access? I know the second commit isn't necessary. It was just from the thing I tried.

Comment: No, it means **literally** what it says... The query returns **no rows**. What **result set** are you expecting from a `GRANT` statement? It doesn't return a result set.

Comment: It doesn't grant permission either.

Comment: does the user you're connecting to the db with have permissions to grant select? does the target user exist? have you tried running the command in SSMS or Azure Data Studio with the same login ?

Comment: There was a coding problemI made. Thank you for your support. Problem solved. The above code is working. I figured out that I solved the problem with "autocommit" but made mistake while logging.